# what are the differences (and when to use) selenium-webdriver over webdriverjs?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm an experience professional that uses selenium-webdriver. I'm exploring more options on how to test javascript applications and I found webdriverJs. Unfortunately, I dont understand what's the difference between these two (2).

Can someone please explain when to use selenium-webdriver over webdriverJs and the benefits?

Thanks!

Comment: General note: WebdriverJS is now called WebdriverIO and should be installed with `npm install webdriverio`. You can still `npm install webdriverjs` but it is deprecated and that NPM project is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WebDriverJS and selenium-webdriver are both JavaScript bindings for the Webdriver API.

The only difference is that selenium-webdriver is the official implementation maintained by the selenium team, whereas WebDriverJS is not. WebDriverJS is maintained by a third-party.

Comment: yes, i understand that. in terms of its used "testing web applications", does it really matter what to use?

Comment: not at all.. although, i might note that Selenium was originally a Java project so i think it's safe to assume that Java is the most tested, and used.  I'd recommend going that way, but it's ALL dependent on what your systems need, and what is nice.  Here where I work, it's a Java shop.  If you worked with Ruby mainly, don't stray too far away from that. use the Ruby api.  If your apps are node js, i'd recommend webdriver js.  It's all up to you.

Comment: I see thanks. so basically, what you are saying both webdriver and webdriverJs do the same job? It just a matter of preference what language to write your test.

Comment: I'm saying WebDriverJS is just the JavaScript port of the Selenium WebDriver API.  Are you familiar with what WebDriver is?  my gut says no.  You may want to read up some history on Selenium RC vs WebDriver.  Unfortunately it's too long of a discussion to put in a comment / answer.  And yes - it really is just a matter of preference what language you write.  Selenium has several ports.  Java, Python, JS, Ruby, PHP, C#, I could go on.  WebDriverJS is simply the official JS version.

Comment: @sircapsalot: I have just realized you might have got this wrong. Confusingly, there are `npm install webdriverjs` and `npm install selenium-webdriver` both being JavaScript bindings of WebDriver. The latter is the official Selenium project one, the first is a separate one. Probably this is what OP's asking about. So in OP's context, `selenium-webdriver` and `webdriverjs` are referring to those two different node.js packages.

Comment: @user1177636 interesting!  i've upvoted the other answer as it actually answers the OP's question :)

Answer (score 27):

They do basically the same thing. The main difference is how you write your tests. selenium-webdriver is a mix of promises and callbacks - WebdriverIO only works with promises and can be used as standalone or with an internal testrunner. There is also a library called wd.js. Here is an example of how all three flavors.

selenium-webdriverjs:

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('btnG')).click();
```

WD.js

```
browser
   .get("http://www.google.com")
   .elementById('q')
   .sendKeys('webdriver')
   .elementById('btnG')
   .click()
```

[WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io):

```
browser
    .url('http://google.com')
    .setValue('#q','webdriver')
    .click('#btnG')
```

WebdriverIOs concept is to wrap all protocol commands in handy action commands but it has also almost all protocol commands implemented, so you can do the same with the standard JSONWire protocol commands.

```
browser
    .url('http://google.com')
    .element('#q').then(function(res) {
        return browser.elementIdValue(res.value.ELEMENT, 'webdriver');
    })
    .element('#btnG').then(function(res) {
        return browser.elementIdClick(res.value.ELEMENT);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. In your opinion, why and when do you use webdriverJs?

Comment: I use WebdriverJS for all my selenium tests. It is super simple and highly extendable. But as maintainer of this library I may have a different opinion on this than other.

Answer (score 0):

I read the official documentation of NPM and seems that the 'accepted' answer on this thread is now incorrect ( It is possible that at the time of the original post the answer was correct ). You can review the official NPM document -

- For WebDriverJS => https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverjs

The document says -

> Project is now called WebdriverIO and has moved to webdriverio/webdriverio on GitHub. Please use $ npm install webdriverio because this NPM project is not maintained anymore!

- For selenium-webdriverjs => https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriverjs

The document says -

> This package has been deprecated. Author message: End of life. Upstream has released an official package: selenium-webdriver

Hence the **only official Selenium-JavaScript library** is [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)

Hope this helps!