# What is difference between webElement and ElementFinder in Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, protractor

Have read Protractor API documentation and watched one guy's video on Youtube. But didn't make it clear for myself.
Is ElementFinder kind of shortcut or pointer to webElement, and Element is instance of some kind of class representing webpage elements'?

Comment: Element is a native javascript class; doesn't have anything to do with protractor

Comment: so, ElementFinder is kind of wrapper to webElement, is it correct to say so?

Comment: Quick google, it looks like the `webElement` is an object that ecapsulates a found Element.  A `ElementFinder` is an object that contains the rule about how to retrieve a webElement upon demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webElement comes from the Selenium code and is propagated up through one of the JavaScript bindings. [WebDriverJS and selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609040/what-are-the-differences-and-when-to-use-selenium-webdriver-over-webdriverjs)

ElementFinder is the [protractor wrapper for webElement](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement).  ElementFinder has extended features that help with the tests stability.  Protractor tends to add extra features in on ElementFinder to make things syntactically easier.